# Android in-app billing/purchase code copying

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm just about adding in-app billing/purchasing to my android app and read through the official training guide at http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html.

What really surprises me is that fact, that I'm instructed to copy and paste classes from a demo application into my production application.

Is this approach recommended? Undoubtably these helper classes are helpful, but isn't there a dependency I can depend on, so the code is pulled via that? Copying code just doesn't feel right...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the IInAppBillingService.aidl file(s) with the code (or classes), yes they are necessary to use the Google Play Store In-App Billing service.

The actual Java code that Google Provides, it just an example about how to use it in an app. If they only gave you the documents, I think you'd be messing around a few hours trying to figure out how the In-App Billing works. You can copy the example one-by-one but I don't recommend it. Using the names from a example is a bad practice.